# Is it possible to use Custom fields in reports

Tags: youtrack

In youtrack we can make an html report for the release notes. But we want to use a custom field in these reports, is this posible or not?

We use youtrack 6.5 for now but are willing to upgrade to 7.0 if it is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible. Please take a look at and vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JT-14339.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I found that but was hoping something was changed in the last couple of years sins it is pretty old but unfortunatly i think it has not changed.